# Load Custom Configuration Sections from assembly in different folder

Tags: c#

I have a C# application to load custom configuration section from assembly in different folder.

For example:

AppBase: C:\Code

Assembly Folder: C:\Lib\My.Core.dll

I have error says "System can't find specific file". I understand it is caused by different folder. Can I reference it in absolute path?

Here is my config file:

```
<section name="regional" type="My.Core.RegionalSection, My.Core" />
```

Can I make it something like

```
<section name="regional" type="My.Core.RegionalSection, C:\Lib\My.Core" />
```

Comment: Why would you not include the assembly file in your project's bin folder, or in GAC? No matter where your app is deployed to, those places are always immediately available. If you have dependencies outside your project they make your project less deployable and prone to breakage. If your project doesn't need to be deployed, why not copy the assembly file inside it to live? I write custom config sections for apps and never had a case where I want part of it left outside my app.

Comment: Typically, in .NET, you can only put stuff into the same folder or any subfolders thereof. You cannot typically reference things outside your own base folder (and its subfolders)

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot specify a path in a type description.  The CLR looks for assemblies in the GAC or the directory that contains the startup EXE.  You can let it look in subdirectories by using the `<probing>` element in your .config file.  Other paths that are completely unrelated to the startup EXE directory requires implementing the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

Deploying DLLs in the same directory as the EXE is a wise thing to do.  It avoids DLL Hell.

Comment: Do you think there would be any mileage from the `<codeBase>` element http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(v=VS.100).aspx I've not tried it.